# How to exit a while True loop using a different format condition in Python?

Tags: python, loops, input, while-loop, format

I found the following code example online, which exits a `while True` loop by using a specific integer:

```
while True:
i = int(input('Please enter an integer (or 0 to exit):\n'))
if i == 0:
    print("Exiting the Program")
    break
print(f'{i} square is {i ** 2}')
```

I would like to know how to exit the loop using a `str` input (like "exit"), instead of a specific int (0 in this example).
I messed around by creating one input per type:

```
while True:
    i_str = input('Please enter an integer ( or "exit" to exit): ')
    if i_str == "exit":
        print("Exiting the Program")
        break
    i_int = int(input('Please enter an integer (or "exit" to exit): '))
    print(f'{i_int} square is {i_int ** 2}')
```

...but it prints out smth every other try, and throws a ValueError when computing 'exit' on the wrong try.

I basically can't figure out how to implement this properly, neither am I sure that I should even be using two different input formats to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `if-else` and convert to `int` if it is not `exit` as:

```
while True:
    i_str = input('Please enter an integer ( or "exit" to exit): ')
    if i_str == "exit":
        print("Exiting the Program")
        break
    else:
        i_int = int(i_str)
        print(f'{i_int} square is {i_int ** 2}')
```

Comment: Glad to be of help, @Effojire, please consider accepting the answer if it resolved your problem.

Comment: Upvoted and accepted.
Upvote won't show as I'm a newbie here. 
Thanks for letting me know abt the accepting option, had no idea there was such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

you can just cast it to a string first and validate it then cast it to int and then put that all in a try-catch to catch any exceptions you can use the example below

```
while True:
try:
    i = str(input('Please enter an integer (or 0 to exit):\n'))
    if "exit" in i:
        print("Exiting the Program")
        break
    else:
        i = int(i)
    if i == 0:
        print("Exiting the Program")
        break
    print(f'{i} square is {i ** 2}')
except:
    print("Exiting the Program")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `try-except`, program will raise an exception if it is unable to convert the entered number to integer.

```
while True:
    try:
        i = int(input('Please enter an integer ( or "exit" to exit): '))
        print(f'{i} square is {i ** 2}')
    except:
        print("Exiting the Program")
        break
```